# Downsampling excessively sampled curves

Tags: r, sampling, resampling

I'm looking for a quick (event if not so accurate) way to deal with over-sampled curves using R. Consider the following example in which `x` contains 1000 values in the range [0, 1) and `y` is some function of `x`.

```
x <- sort(runif(1000))
y <- sin(x)
```

I'm looking for a way to take only 100 points on this curve, preferably in equal intervals, without knowing the actual model that produces `y`'s from `x`'s. My naiive approach is to find indices of original `x` values that are closest to the new ones:

```
x.new <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
y.new <- c()
for(x.val in x.new){
  ix <- which.min((x.val - x) ** 2) #closest value in x
  y.new <- c(y.new, y[ix])
}
```

Or, using a `sapply`

```
find.closest.y <- function(v){
  return(y[which.min((v - x)**2)])
}

y.new <- sapply(x.new, find.closest.y)
```

I'm OK with the accuracy of this method, but I suspect that there is a way to acheive this using functions from standard R libraries. Am I right? Is there a simpler method to downsample curves?

Comment: If you could share a little more information about what you plan to do with these curves and why you want to downsample them, it is possible you might get some excellent and creative answers. For instance, it occurs to me that if (say) you planned on using a cubic spline to interpolate the downsampled version, then an adaptive algorithm (akin to the Douglas-Peucker method of simplifying a polyline) could be applied to maximize the accuracy of the spline. For the example given, it is conceivable that extremely high accuracy would be achieved with very aggressive downsampling.

Comment: I have a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686200/min-distance-algorithm-in-r , I downsample in order to plot the "fewest necessary" points from a huge data set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are bunches of good algorithms to do that. They are known as
*data compression* algorithms, and are widely used for biomedical data
such as EEG. I recommend the *fan algorithm* which while being fairly simple
gives nice results in many situations. It does not seem to be available 
in R packages but is easily implemented.  See e.g a course by Carlos E. Davila,

[lyle.smu.edu/~cd/EE5345/lect11_spr00.PDF](http://lyle.smu.edu/~cd/EE5345/lect11_spr00.PDF)

Most data compression algorithms work on regularly sampled signal $x_t$ 
and build online an irregular sampling at a low cost. Some run *ex post* 
with a small delay, as the fan algorithm do.

For purely graphics purpose there are very efficient methods based on
Bezier Splines, which are natively supported by some graphical languages
as pdf or SVG. Goggle searches may bring you what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the keyword you're looking for is "interpolation". A default R install has the function 'loess', which may fit the bill. Also 'smooth.spline' and 'spline'. Package 'akima' has 'aspline'. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an average of the two nearest values be a better estimate for y.new[ix] than

```
  y.new <- c(y.new, y[ix])
```

Perhaps even a lever arm weighted average depending on how relatively near    x.val     is to the two nearest points?